# Winform calling ASP.NET Web API with Claims

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I have a Winform client that we are slowing changing inline SQL data calls into ASP.NET Web API calls. We currently use the WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole check in the Winform client to determine if the user can run the SQL data calls. We would like to move into a Claims type setup where both the Winform client and the Web API can check the roles "claims" of a user.

I can't seem to find any "good" articles on how to get a Winform client to (1. Pass the claim to the service) and (2. Use a claim check inside the Winform client like the IsInRole). Any help or push in the right direction would be great.

--EDIT

So I used this article http://zamd.net/2012/05/04/claim-based-security-for-asp-net-web-apis-using-dotnetopenauth/ as a sample on getting a token back from the server but the article does not show how to get the claims identity out of the http client. Any idea how to get the claims identity out of the http client?

Comment: Just a thought - instead of "passing claims", would auth before talking to API work? On the other hand, or in addition to it, you could pass a "token" (signed) which you can validate on the Web API side (before the WebAPI does anything). Hth....

Comment: I have figured out how to call a custom OAuth2 server to get a token at the winform client and I then pass the token to the Web API service. At the Web API service I found some code "httpContext.User = ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromIdentity" that I can use to set the thread identity on the server. I am still missing code on how to set the thread identity = claims principal at the Winform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I haven't tested this code, hopefully it will get you moving in the right direction.

I believe to answer your question you do this in your ClaimsAuthenticationManager where upon validating the token received from the server you set the **Thread.CurrentPrincipal** *-- the same way you do on the web side without setting the HttpContext.Current.User principal.*

***Again this isn't tested but I think it would look something like this...***

In my Token Validator I have the following code:

```
    public static ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(new JwtSecurityToken(token),
            Constants.TokenValidationParameters);

        return FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration
            .IdentityConfiguration
            .ClaimsAuthenticationManager.Authenticate(token, claimsPrincipal);
    }

    public static string GetToken(string username, string password)
    {
        OAuth2Client client = Constants.OAuth2Client;
        AccessTokenResponse response = client.RequestAccessTokenUserName(username.ToLower(), password,
            Constants.AllowedAudience);
        return response.AccessToken;
    }
```

Within my ClaimsAuthenticationManager I have modified the following code as you don't want to set the HttpContext in a non web environment:

```
 public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }

        /* HttpContext.Current.User = */ Thread.CurrentPrincipal = incomingPrincipal;

        return incomingPrincipal;
    }
```

I believe you then just have to set the appropriate keys in the app.config, specifically the `system.identityModel => identityConfiguration => claimsAuthenticationManager`

Once the thread you are running on has the "Authenticated Principal" you should be able to call the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.HasClaim() or your higher level Authorization.CheckAccess()` function to validate sections of your WinForm logic.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Here is a cool little site to help you see whats in your tokens... [link](http://jwt.calebb.net)